# Elementary theme will not install

Tags: package-management, apt, nautilus-elementary

I really like Elementary themes and I now want to install the Elementary theme on my new re-installation of Ubuntu. So when I typed this in

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-theme
```

and started the process it prompted:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I then pressed `y` but it still aborted.

[image]

Is there any other way to install the full theme or to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried this multiple times?

Comment: yes, and it justs abort...is their a deb?

Comment: What PPA are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I found an alternative and in fact is better as the wallpapers are breathtaking and amazing.
.
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-wallpapers`

Comment: Did you add elementary ppa?

Answer (score -2):

in case of elementary theme, compiz is not compatibile. window decoration is broken. elementary team work to eliminate gtk2 component in theme in all aspect. in this moment meny things is build-up on ppa so try "elementarysh" theme from http://gnome-look.org/.
in all, importing ppa just for theme is not smart move. if you like elementary os, try to install complete DE via ppa (is dally but verry stabile).

Comment: What are you talking about? they haven't removed any gtk2 support. The theme doesn't support gtk 3.6 which is another story. It also doesn't have anything to do with compiz or anything you mention for that matter, window decorations are fine they're for metacity.

Comment: am say that they want to remuve, not is remuved. elementary default theme is not work with compiz (gtk2 component) window decoration is ugly